# Error in Google Custom Search API nexpage

Tags: python, google-api

Google Custom API search code I wrote

```
import time
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Google custom search API info
API_KEY = 'My Key'
API_ID = 'My ID'


def spider_next_page(service, index, searchterm_in, incl_searchterm_in, sitesearch_in):
    time.sleep(1)
    response = service.cse().list(
        q=searchterm_in,
        orTerms=incl_searchterm_in,
        siteSearch=sitesearch_in,
        cx=my_cse_id,
        num=10,
        start=index,
    ).execute()

    nextPageIndex = response['queries']['nextPage'][0]['startIndex']
    nextPageCount = response['queries']['nextPage'][0]['count']

    for values_spider_next_page in response['items']:
        itemsave.append(values_spider_next_page)

    if nextPageIndex == 21:
        pageno = ((nextPageIndex - 1) / 10)
        print('Found', round(pageno), "Pages")
        return

    if nextPageCount != 0:
        spider_next_page(service, nextPageIndex, searchterm_in, incl_searchterm_in, sitesearch_in)


def spider(searchterm_in, incl_searchterm_in, sitesearch_in):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1",
                    developerKey=my_api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(
        q=searchterm_in,
        orTerms=incl_searchterm_in,
        siteSearch=sitesearch_in,
        cx=my_cse_id,
    ).execute()
    searchterm_in = res['queries']['request'][0]['searchTerms']
    nextPageIndex = res['queries']['nextPage'][0]['startIndex']
    nextPageCount = res['queries']['nextPage'][0]['count']
    print('nextPageIndex', nextPageIndex)
    print("Search Query:", searchterm_in)
    print("Include Query :", incl_searchterm_in)
    print("Target Site :", sitesearch_in)

    for values_spider in res['items']:

        itemsave.append(values_spider)

    if nextPageCount != 0:
        spider_next_page(service, nextPageIndex, searchterm_in, incl_searchterm_in, sitesearch_in)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_api_key = API_KEY
    my_cse_id = API_ID
    itemsave = []
    spider('men shorts', 'adidas', 'yahoo.com')
```

Normally, data can be obtained without errors, but sometimes the errors below occur.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D://Google_Search_API_0.4.py", line 122, in <module>
    spider(f'{searchterm}', f'{incl_searchterm}', f'{sitesearch}')
  File "D://Google_Search_API_0.4.py", line 70, in spider
    nextPageIndex = res['queries']['nextPage'][0]['startIndex']
KeyError: 'nextPage'
```

It works in the following order.

> spider('men shorts', 'adidas', 'yahoo.com') # input query (q,orTerms,siteSearch)

> spider(searchterm_in, incl_searchterm_in, sitesearch_in): # first page -> get input query

> spider_next_page(service, index, searchterm_in, incl_searchterm_in, sitesearch_in): # next page

If an error occurs, it occurs here.

```
def spider(searchterm_in, incl_searchterm_in, sitesearch_in):
    ...
   --> nextPageIndex = res['queries']['nextPage'][0]['startIndex']
```

If I'm right, what's the problem? And why does it sometimes work without errors?

Comment: maybe it is end of data so there is no more `nextPage`. You could use `try/except` to catch error or you should run it in `if 'nextPage' in res['queries']:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is the end of data so there is no more `nextPage`.

You could use `try/except` to catch error and skip code.

Or you should run it in `if 'nextPage' in res['queries']:`

```
if 'nextPage' not in res['queries']:`
    print("The End")

else:
    nextPageIndex = response['queries']['nextPage'][0]['startIndex']
    nextPageCount = response['queries']['nextPage'][0]['count']

    for values_spider_next_page in response['items']:
        itemsave.append(values_spider_next_page)

    if nextPageIndex == 21:
        pageno = ((nextPageIndex - 1) / 10)
        print('Found', round(pageno), "Pages")
        return

    if nextPageCount != 0:
        spider_next_page(service, nextPageIndex, searchterm_in, incl_searchterm_in, sitesearch_in)
```

Comment: I  have one more question. How do I print the current request URL in my code? I'd like to put in the URL where each page number comes from.

Comment: I don't know if you can get it. It can be hidden somewhere in code and not avaliable for user. All modules for different APIs are created to work only with functions without using URLs. You would have to digg in documentation or even in source code to get it.

Comment: oh. I see. if so, I will just put next page only. It was very helpful!!